# D3JS - animate a circle along an svg path at a constant speed

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, d3.js, transition

I'd like to move a circle along a path using d3.js. I used the code from Mike Bostocks' website here:

http://bl.ocks.org/KoGor/8162640

I'd like to move my circle at a constant speed along the path and have it moving immediately after it has been added to my svg. I cannot see how to twist the code here to make it work.

Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

Best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just add a line

```
.ease("linear")
```

after `.duration(7500)`, and you should be all set.

This is [documentation on ease()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#ease), but you should read all that is related to transitions, while you ate at it...

[Here is also a test example](http://bl.ocks.org/hunzy/9929724) for various possibilities related to `ease()`:

[image]